# How do I query using a variable value in mongodb from R?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am new in rmongodb. I would like to make a query in one collection in MongoDB using the value of a variable. It goes like this:

```
 OBS_ID<-"20150510120000"

 QUERY_DATA<-mongo.find.all(MONGO, "prod.CUSTDATA", query='{"Obs_ID" :
 OBS_ID}')
```

This code doesn't work. I can not find any related documentation in rmongodb on how to deal with this.

Looking forward for your answers! Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess: `QUERY_DATA<-mongo.find.all(MONGO, "prod.CUSTDATA", query=paste0('{"Obs_ID" : ,OBS_ID,'}')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [dbGetQuery](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RMongo/docs/dbGetQuery) as below :

```
library('RMongo')
dbName <- mongoDbConnect('dbname')
query <- dbGetQuery(dbName,'collectionName',"{'Obs_ID' : '20150510120000'}")
```

Comment: I am using rmongodb package, not RMongo. Besides, this query is still based on a static value of OBS_ID. I would like to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution to this problem. I need to create a mongo.bson.buffer object.

> ## Set up the query
>
> OBS_ID<-"20150510120000"
>
> buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
> mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf,"Obs_ID")
> mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf,"$eq",OBS_ID)
> criteria <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
>
> ## Query from MongoDB using the criteria
>
> QUERY<-mongo.find.all(MONGO, "prod.CUSTDATA", query=criteria)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, although I am using mongolite, the idea may be useful for you:

```
   library (mongolite)
   con = mongo(...) #your data to connect to your mongoDB
   fquery <- (paste0("{\"","Obs_ID\"",":\"", OBS_ID, "\"}")) #create the query
   mydata <- con$find(fquery) #retrieve data
```

Note: use ", Mongo will not accept '.

Best!